# Как извлечь регулярное выражение из строки?/How to extract a regular expression from a string?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как правильно разбить строку такого вида, на шаблон и флаги? При условии, что иногда флагов в строке может и не быть?

```
const stringRexExp = '/^qwe\\/rty$/ui';
```

UPD

```
// достать флаги flags[0], если нет то ''
const flags = stringRexExp.match(/(g|i|m|u|s|y){0,6}$/);
// вырезать паттерн
const pattern = stringRexExp.slice(1, flags.index);

const re = new RexExp(pattern, flags);
```

Comment: `eval(stringRexExp).flags` -> `iu`, `eval(stringRexExp).source` -> `^qwe\/rty$`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string = '/^qwe\/rty$/ui'
const re = /^(\/.*\/)(\S+)?$/g;

console.log(string.split(re).filter(e => e));
```

Comment: Спасибо, я только до этого додумался 
const flags = stringRexExp.match(/(g|i|m|u|s|y){0,6}$/)[0]
const template = stringRexExp.slice(1, (flags.length > 0) ? -flags.length : stringRexExp.length)

Comment: @Noob, если ответ вам чем-то помог, то можете нажать зеленую галочку рядом с ним, чтобы принять его